# Upstart Job as Unprivileged user fails with permission denied

Tags: upstart

I'm trying to set up a Sage Cell Server (an open source mathematical engine) running as an unprivileged user. I've created the unprivileged user `sagecell` to do the job. It is installed correctly and, if I run it normally using

```
sagecell@primary-server:~/sage/devel/sagecell$ ../../sage web_server.py
```

then everything works as expected. An interesting requirement of this application (that may or may not be relevant) is that it requires a passwordless ssh login (i.e., `ssh localhost` works). I've set up the unprivileged account with an ssh-key to do the job.

Now, rather than manually making a screen session after booting up the server and running it in a screen session, I tried making an upstart job with this setup:

```
description "Sage Cell Server Starter"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc runlevel=[016]

kill timeout 5

exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' sagecell -- /home/sagecell/sage/sage /home/sagecell/sage/devel/sagecell/web_server.py
```

This, however, does not work. Looking at /var/log/upstart/sagecell.log gives the following error:

```
2013-02-20 00:11:09,665 sagecell:INFO starting tornado web server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sagecell/sage/devel/sagecell/web_server.py", line 78, in <module>
    application = SageCellServer()
  File "/home/sagecell/sage/devel/sagecell/web_server.py", line 57, in __init__
    kernel_timeout=kernel_timeout)
  File "/home/sagecell/sage-5.7.rc0/devel/sagecell-main/trusted_kernel_manager.py", line 28, in __init__
    self._sender = sender.AsyncSender() # Manages asynchronous communication
  File "/home/sagecell/sage-5.7.rc0/devel/sagecell-main/sender.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.router.bind(self.filename)
  File "socket.pyx", line 489, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.bind (zmq/core/socket.c:4797)
zmq.core.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
```

EDIT: It should be noted that the application binds to port 8080 (and only 8080 as far as I'm aware). The important thing is that it works without privileges when I run it but not when Upstart runs it as the same user.

Can anyone tell me why an application that works perfectly fine under the user `sagecell` fails to run under an upstart job running the script AS `sagecell`?

Comment: Is the socket already in use?

Comment: No, it is not. I can successfully start it from the command line, just not as an upstart job.